# Audio file won't play back?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My audio file won't play.

```
- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* foofile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameStringAudio];

    NSLog(@"TRYING TO PLAY %@", foofile);


    NSURL *murl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath :foofile];
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *players = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:murl error:&error];
    players.numberOfLoops = 1;

    [players play];
}
```

NOTE: my NSLog result is "TRYING TO PLAY /var/mobile/Applications/XXXXXXXXXXXX/Documents/1400512882.m4a"

Answer (score 1):

`*players` is not being retained. Make it a property. And make sure the audio file is copied into the Documents directory.